# Salutation to use in a business email to a German lady written in English

Tags: germany, business

I'm dealing with a German company, hunting for a flat. So far I have filled in a web-form and one of their agents has got back to me. She has addressed me as:

```
Dear Mr [Lastname]
```

My understanding of German business customs is that I should remain formal for now.

I believe that if we were corresponding in German, I would simply use:

```
Sehr geehrte Frau [Lastname]
```

but we are communicating in English and if there's one thing you can trust the British to do, it's mess around with formality. I've now got the options of `Mrs` / `Miss` / `Ms`, with no way of knowing the lady's marital status.

tldr; is `Ms` acceptable to use to address a lady in Germany?

If answers could also address the German salutation, it might be useful for future visitors to this question.

Comment: This forum thread https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=4145 recommends Ms. which would seem the most reasonable approach. I know of the German reputation for preciseness however most people with any kind of global experience recognize and overlook small failures in correspondence social formalities.

Comment: [german.se] Stack Exchange may be helpful also.

Comment: It's not uncommon to use foreign titles in English, so "Dear Frau X" wouldn't be too bad an option.  You might even address her in German as "Sehr geehrte Frau X" even though the rest of the letter is in English, perhaps along with a brief apology for not writing in German if you haven't already done that.

Comment: Hello Mis david how are you doing today please help me to protect my account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In German, the marital status is no longer of concern for addressing a person (cf. [*Fräulein*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A4ulein), which is the equivalent of *Miss*). You’ll typically only use *Herr* and *Frau*, even if you know that they are/aren’t married.

The English translations would be ***Mr***/***Mr.*** (for *Herr*) and ***Ms***/***Ms.*** (for *Frau*).

So in your case, you should write:

> Dear Ms [Lastname]